# .htaccess 301 redirecting --> retrieve CSS style sheet from redirected directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

With the help of my .htaccess file, I was able to redirect all requests made on `mydomain.com/folder/` or on any of it's subdomains to `mydomain.com` as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /folder/(.*) //
```

However, I happened to ran into a problem. I have a CSS style sheet at `mydomain.com/folder/style.css` and I want to link it to a HTML file at `mydomain.com/file.html`, but the HTML fails to recognize and/or open the CSS style sheet. Nevertheless, I know that the file path used to point to the style sheet is correct.

Could anyone possibly point me to the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by _"fails to recognize and/or open the CSS style sheet"_? What error you have? Need more details.

Comment: It displays no errors, the CSS style sheet just doesn't "work" or affect the output of the HTML file in any way.

Comment: Is that site available online? Can you post such "bad" URL so I can look into it? As right now it is unclear for me what is going on -- your description gives me no ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: I do not think the link would give anything, either.
Domain: http://pood.net23.net/
Redirected directory: http://pood.net23.net/http://pood.net23.net/S1hU3uS0nI9t_mallid/
CSS file: http://pood.net23.net/S1hU3uS0nI9t_mallid/tpl_epood_oh/css/stiil.css

Comment: Sorry, but it redirects me to `http://pood.net23.net/` for every URL.

Comment: That was the point in the first place.

There are template files in that directory and those files are retrieved with PHP. They work just fine.
However, when I try to use a CSS style sheet from the directory, it doesn't work, because the server redirects the page back to the root directory of the domain.

What I want to know is whether or not there is a way that the CSS file can be left untouched, but all other places in that directory still be redirected to the root directory of the domain?

Comment: Now it is clear what you want. Sure, that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule instead of yours -- it will redirect ALL requests that start with `/folder/` EXCEPT `/folder/style.css`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/((?!style\.css).*) /
```